# mySQL and html form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I've made a form with the help of bootstrap studio and I've already created a database and established a connection using php.
Here's just the html(no css)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Login-Form-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Registration-Form-with-Photo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-dark" style="background-image:url(&quot;assets/img/login-background.jpg&quot;);background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
</div>

            <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
            </div><a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot your email or password?</a></form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the php:

```
<?php
include('includes/DB.php');
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo submitted;
    //Runs query to see if username exists
    if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
        //Runs query to search for password
        $passwordDB = DB::query('SELECT password FROM users where username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'];
        //Checks if password already exists
        if($password==$passwordDB) {
            echo 'Logged in!';
            header('Location: main-page');
            //Create cookiee  for user to be logged in
            $cstrong = True;


     $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
            $user_id = DB::query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username", array('username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
            //store token in database
            //sha1 will hash the token
            DB::query("INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES ('', :token, :user_id)",array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));

            //cookie to log the user in
            //cookie will be valid for 1 week (time()+60*60*24*7)
            setcookie("SNID",$token, time()+60*60*24*7, '/', NULL,NULL,TRUE);
            setcookie("SNID_",1,time()+60*60*24*3, '/', NULL,NULL,TRUE);
            header('Location: main-page.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect Password!';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'User not registered!';
    }
};
?>
```

However, when I log in, nothing happens. It's supposed to echo out logged in and then redirect me to another page
(I'm using XAMPP with phpmyadmin if that helps)

I've tried to add

```
include("login.html");
```

on top of the php file, however it makes no difference.

Before I used bootstrap studio I created a simple plain html form and it worked, as soon as I used bootsrap studio to make the form look nicer, I got this problem.
Fairly new to php and mySQL, how could I fix it?

Comment: 1- why did you include the file after closing the body tag? 2- you wont be able to see this output: echo 'Logged in!'; because you will be redirected to the page. it is so fast you wont see it

Comment: sugar, that was a mistake from when I copied and pasted the code, in my actual file i don't have include as it didnt do anything. I'll change it now

Comment: Also, echo submitted; won't work.

Comment: @emre Oh yeah, there's supposed to be speech marks around it, fixed it but that's not really the main issue

Comment: You are having that problem because the header is sent before you see the output. You have 2 headers. Remove the first one: header('Location: main-page'); And add die (); after the second one. You will see that the text will be displayed

Comment: @emre still didn't work, been searching everywhere not really sure what to do

Comment: Save your php  file as login.php and add <?php include("login.php");  ?> just after <body> tag. Remove the first header('Location: main-page'); keep the second one. Tell me what you see

Comment: @emre still nothing

Comment: Do you get any error

Comment: Your html form is not right either

Comment: Add name="login" after type="submit" in html

Comment: @emre still nothing, I don't even get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know what is displayed.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Login-Form-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Registration-Form-with-Photo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-dark" style="background-image:url(&quot;assets/img/login-background.jpg&quot;);background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
</div>

            <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="login">Log In</button>
            </div><a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot your email or password?</a></form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Php

```
<?php
include('includes/DB.php');
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo "username: ";
    echo $username;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "password: ";
    echo $password;

    //Runs query to see if username exists
    if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
        //Runs query to search for password
        $passwordDB = DB::query('SELECT password FROM users where username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'];
        //Checks if password already exists
        if($password==$passwordDB) {
            echo 'Logged in!';
            //Create cookiee  for user to be logged in
            $cstrong = True;


     $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
            $user_id = DB::query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username", array('username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
            //store token in database
            //sha1 will hash the token
            DB::query("INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES ('', :token, :user_id)",array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));

            //cookie to log the user in
            //cookie will be valid for 1 week (time()+60*60*24*7)
            setcookie("SNID",$token, time()+60*60*24*7, '/', NULL,NULL,TRUE);
            setcookie("SNID_",1,time()+60*60*24*3, '/', NULL,NULL,TRUE);

            die();
            header('Location: main-page.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect Password!';
            die();
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'User not registered!';
        die();
    }
};
?>
```

Comment: printed out the username and password that I entered on a new page but im not actually logged in

Comment: You legend! Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please tell me exactly what you changed? I want to learn from this massively colossally long mistake.

Comment: the code is not complete. Currently it dies before directing you to the main-page.php, I was trying to go step by step to see the fault. If you don't want to redirect user than you need to remove this line: header('Location: main-page.php');